# R: combining data-frames row-wise when some variables are lists/dfs?

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation

Is there a function in R that would let me combine/concatenate data-frames when some variables are either lists or data frames themselves? I've tried `rbind()`, `rbindlist()`, `rbind.data.frame` and `bind_rows` and they are all throwing out errors, e.g. `duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed` or `Argument 4 can't be a list containing data frames`.

After looking into it a bit, it seems that none of those functions support nested data-frames. Is there a function that would work for me? Or is there something (other than a for-loop that adds row by row) that I could do?

As a bit of a background, I'm making API-calls to a database and can get only 40 results at a time so I am looping through those via multiple calls, and I want to combine the results without any loss of information. I am using `jsonlite:fromJSON` to convert to a df: could I/should I combine the info in JSON format first and then convert to a df?

Comment: could you provide with an example of your nested dataframes?